# Another word for "long run impact"

Tags: synonyms

What is a poetic word for "long run impact"? to decribe some event in the past which still leave something until tens of years later?

Comment: Have you done any research?  What did you find out?

Comment: @Xanne already, but nothing was found :( Im thinking of the word "trace" or "remnant", but it's not exactly the one...

Comment: Well, look up "impact" and "consequences".

Comment: @cherrykate, Please provide an example sentence with a dash. Then our readers can easily suggest suitable words.

Comment: @mahmudkoya thanks! actually it is just a title of my research project.Im about to put it like "the long run impact of war on current marital status" for example... so i just want to alternate it a bit more poetic... :)

Comment: Do you really mean **marital** *status*?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if any of these words/phrases will be helpful: ***aftermath, aftereffect, consequence, the bitter fruits of sth, knock-on effect,  etc.***

Comment: @madmudkoya: yea, marital status or bad health etc..

Comment: many thanks for those words. I think "the bitter fruits" could be perfectly used!!